# How do I get a list of apps appropriate for users?

Tags: spotlight

I want to fetch a list of runnable app appropriate for users. I tried a lot of combinations usind `mdfind`, but none of them shows up only nice, runnable apps using an icon, while also providing the system apps buried in the CoreServices folder (Finder, Computer, Network ...).

Note: I actually try to interface the spotlight API programmatically but the interface is more or less the same.

The problem:

If I set the search scope to

```bash
mdfind \
    -onlyin ~/Applications \
    -onlyin /Applications \
    -onlyin /System/Applications \
    -onlyin /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications \
    "kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle' && kMDItemKind == 'Programm'" \
    | sort
```

I get a good set of Apps. But e.g. Finder.app is in `/System/Library/CoreServices/` if I use this scope it finds a bunch of apps users should not be able to run easily, like rcd.app languagechooser.app etc. Things that make it easy to break your system.

Is there some sort of filter I can use to get sophisitcated results?

Comment: What do you define as a “runnable app appropriate for users?”  What `mdfind` searches did you execute?  What were the results?  What do you expect the results to be?

Comment: Surely all 'runnable apps appropriate for users' will be in /Applications?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Why are you searching `/System/...`?  These give you the built in Apps that the user can already use.  You only need to search two places for Installed Applications:  `/Applications` and `/Users/<USERNAME>/Applications`

Comment: I am writing an applicatoin launcher and try to port it to macos. I need all apps a user may be interested in

Comment: "all apps a user may be interested in" is quite broad in scope and difficult to define.  Start with the two directories I supplied.  That will give you all **user** Applications (including Utilities) that are included with the system as well anything installed by an Admin.  Finder is the windowing system.  It would be like giving a user access to `windows.exe` on a PC.

Comment: And the file browser right?

Comment: Finder is (at least partly) the file browser (equivalent to explorer.exe on Windows) but a user never needs to launch it as it is always running and macOS runs it automatically at login. While there are applications buried everywhere in macOS 99.99% of people will never want, nor need, to run them. Like @Allan said stick to the two user accessible Applications folders and that should do it.

Comment: Well somehow I need the applications plugin to open fire Browsers hol mal supposed to open Finder programmatically or macOS then?